# Mac Mountain Lion / Macports / Python27: Installed, activated but ImportError

Tags: python, macos, macports

I installed Macports and Python27. Actived it, but it does not work? Any clue what went wrong?
I even deleted anything like brew and a previous port installation and rebooted before I installed a fresh copy again.

Thanks in advance.
M

```
macbook-pro-15:~ MR$ sudo port select --list python
    Available versions for python:
        none
        python25-apple
        python26-apple
        python27 (active)
        python27-apple
    macbook-pro-15:~ MR$ python
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 548, in <module>
        main()
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 530, in main
        known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 266, in addusersitepackages
        user_site = getusersitepackages()
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 241, in getusersitepackages
        user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 231, in getuserbase
        USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 516, in get_config_var
        return get_config_vars().get(name)
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 449, in get_config_vars
        import re
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 105, in <module>
        import sre_compile
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 14, in <module>
        import sre_parse
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
        from sre_constants import *
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
        from _sre import MAXREPEAT
    ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
```

Comment: Did you sync to the latest versions? There was a problem with a 2.7 release that exhibited exactly that error, since fixed.

Comment: Martijn, how do I sync? I just installed a fresh version with sudo port install python27.

Comment: Addition: I ran sudo port -d selfupdate and sudo port upgrade outdated. no improvement. BUT I can run python2.7. It works than.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to bash cashing the path to previously launched commands.

The short fix is:

```
$ hash -d python
$ python
```

The longer story: for efficiency, bash caches the path to previously launched
commands. After installing Python through macports, if your system python has already been cached by bash, calling `python` will still call the system python (despite `which python` outputting the macports python version)

```
# Before installing macports
$ python -c 'print "Hello World!"'
Hello World!
$ which python
/usr/bin/python

# Install python27 via macports
sudo port install python27
sudo port select --set python python27

# The shell will still invoke the system python, despite the output of `which`
$ which python # macports
/opt/local/bin/python
$ hash -t python # system
/usr/bin/python
$ python # the shell invokes the executable from the cache, and this gives the error

# clear the cache
$ hash -d python 

# now python should work
python
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. What finally worked for me was simply to uninstall and reinstall python through MacPorts.

```
> sudo port uninstall python27
> sudo port install python27
> sudo port select --set python python27
```

This installed `Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  1 2013, 01:01:17)`.

After uninstalling and reinstalling, make sure to log out of your shell and open new shells. Old shells will still see the same problem.

Comment: Thanks! `make sure to log out of your shell and open new shells` I can't believe it was that simple.